# Set the marker center to the GeoPoint

Tags: android, marker, osmdroid

I'm working on osmdroid, and trying to do something very simple, that i used to do on another map framework, but i can't find how to do it on OSMdroid.
I want to put a marker somewhere on the map, on a GeoPoint. Up to this, it's easy. But i also want the **center** of the marker pic to be on the susmentioned geopoint.
With my code, right now, the geopoint is at the left bottom corner of the image.

How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I found it. So I'm answering my question in case somebody has the same problem.

I tried first your idea woodstock, but i failed to find a boundCenter Method.

So in order to make the GeoPoint the center of the drawable, you just need to do that:

```
overlayItem.setMarker(YourDrawable);
overlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Marker class, then better to use code below...

```
Marker marker = new Marker(map);
marker.setAnchor((float)0.5, (float)0.5); // center icon to geo pint
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used osmdroid before, but you can normally achieve this by setting the bounds of the marker.

For example, when using Google's MapView you would use the following code to specify that you want the center of the marker to be on the given GeoPoint:

```
super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
```

Comment: OK, guys, i found it. So i'm answering my question in case somebody has the same problem.

I tried first your idea woodstock, but i failed to find a boundCenter Method.

So in order to make the GeoPoint the center of the drawable, you just need to do that:

    overlayItem.setMarker(YourDrawable);
    overlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);

Thank you guys.